# Undefined Errors preventing creation of tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, create-table

I get this very nondescript error trying to create my next two tables, I believe its just a mispelling or a missing comma but can't seem to find it. Could someone please check out my code and see what I did wrong here?

Error

```
#1005 - Can't create table './cbw222_inspections/Melons.frm' (errno: 150)

LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
120305 12:33:51 Error in foreign key constraint of table temp/Melons:
FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                   FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
               ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1:

Cannot resolve table name close to:
(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                   FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
               ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

The SQL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customer`;
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (

    `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Customer_Number`       VARCHAR(70),
    `Customer_Name`         VARCHAR(70),
    `Website`               VARCHAR(255),
    `Logo`                  VARCHAR(100),

    PRIMARY KEY(`CustomerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Reports`;
    CREATE TABLE `Reports` (

        `ReportID`              INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `Role`                  VARCHAR(70),
        `Region`                VARCHAR(70),
        `Inpection_Type`        VARCHAR(70),
        `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `Report_Date`           DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
        `Order_Date`            TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `Customer_Name`         VARCHAR(100),
        `Customer_Division`     VARCHAR(70),
        `Memo`                  VARCHAR(255),
        `Billing_Key`           VARCHAR(70),

        PRIMARY KEY(`ReportID`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customer(`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customer_Contact`;
    CREATE TABLE `Customer_Contact` (

        `ContactID`             INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `Division`              VARCHAR(100),
        `Contact`               VARCHAR(100),
        `Address`               VARCHAR(255),
        `Phone`                 VARCHAR(100),
        `Fax`                   VARCHAR(100),
        `Email`                 VARCHAR(100),
        `Mobile`                VARCHAR(100),

        PRIMARY KEY(`ContactID`),
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customer(`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Inspectors`;
CREATE TABLE `Inspectors` (

    `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name`                  VARCHAR(70),
    `Phone`                 VARCHAR(70),
    `Address`               VARCHAR(255),
    `Email`                 VARCHAR(100),
    `Fax`                   VARCHAR(70),

    PRIMARY KEY(`InspectorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Lists`;
    CREATE TABLE `Lists` (

        `ListID`                INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `Commodity`             VARCHAR(70),
        `Region`                VARCHAR(70),
        `Shipper`               VARCHAR(100),
        `Variety`               VARCHAR(70),
        `Style`                 VARCHAR(70),
        `Label`                 VARCHAR(70),
        `Pack_Date`             DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
        `Grower_Lot`            VARCHAR(70),
        `Berry_Size1`           VARCHAR(5),
        `Berry_Size2`           VARCHAR(5),
        `Berry_Size3`           VARCHAR(5),
        `Berry_Size4`           VARCHAR(5),
        `Bunch_Count1`          VARCHAR(5),
        `Bunch_Count2`          VARCHAR(5),
        `Color1`                VARCHAR(15),
        `Color2`                VARCHAR(15),
        `Rating`                VARCHAR(25),
        `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `Comments`              VARCHAR(255),

        PRIMARY KEY(`ListID`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Melons`;
            CREATE TABLE `Melons` (

                `MelonsID`              INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `ReportID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Status`                ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                `PO`                    VARCHAR(15),
                `Location`              VARCHAR(75),
                `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Commodity`             VARCHAR(25),
                `Count`                 VARCHAR(20),
                `Size`                  VARCHAR(20),
                `Label`                 VARCHAR(100),
                `Variety`               VARCHAR(25),
                `Pack_Date`             DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
                `Grower_Lot`            VARCHAR(25),
                `Color1`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Color2`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Ground_Color1`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Ground_Color2`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Texture1`              VARCHAR(5),
                `Texture2`              VARCHAR(5),
                `Scar1`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Scar2`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Solidity1`             VARCHAR(5),
                `Solidity2`             VARCHAR(5),
                `Cut1`                  VARCHAR(5),
                `Cut2`                  VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix1`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix2`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Rating`                VARCHAR(35),
                `Comments`              VARCHAR(255),

                PRIMARY KEY(`MelonsID`),
                FOREIGN KEY (`ReportID`) REFERENCES Reports(`ReportID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Melon_Photos`;
                CREATE TABLE `Melon_Photos` (

                    `PhotoID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `MelonsID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                    `Photo`                 VARCHAR(70),
                    `Caption`               VARCHAR(255),
                    `Catalog`               VARCHAR(50),

                    PRIMARY KEY(`MelonsID`),
                    FOREIGN KEY (`MelonsID`) REFERENCES Melons(`MelonsID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Table_Grapes`;
            CREATE TABLE `Table_Grapes` (

                `GrapeID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `ReportID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Status`                ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                `PO`                    VARCHAR(15),
                `Location`              VARCHAR(75),
                `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Commodity`             VARCHAR(25),
                `Pack_Type`             VARCHAR(35),
                `Count`                 VARCHAR(20),
                `Label`                 VARCHAR(100),
                `Variety`               VARCHAR(25),
                `Style`                 VARCHAR(35),
                `Pack_Date`             DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
                `Grower_Lot`            VARCHAR(25),
                `Berry_Sizing1`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing2`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing3`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing4`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Bunch_Count1`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Bunch_Count2`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Color1`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Color2`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Stem_Cond1`            VARCHAR(15),
                `Stem_Cond2`            VARCHAR(15),
                `Stem_Cond3`            VARCHAR(15),
                `Shatter1`              VARCHAR(5),
                `Shatter2`              VARCHAR(5),
                `Decay_Count1`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Decay_Count2`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Sugar_Brix1`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix2`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Rating`                VARCHAR(35),
                `Comments`              VARCHAR(255),

                PRIMARY KEY(`GrapeID`),
                FOREIGN KEY (`ReportID`) REFERENCES Reports(`ReportID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Grape_Photos`;
                CREATE TABLE `Grape_Photos` (

                    `PhotoID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `GrapeID`               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                    `Photo`                 VARCHAR(70),
                    `Caption`               VARCHAR(255),
                    `Catalog`               VARCHAR(50),

                    PRIMARY KEY(`GrapeID`),
                    FOREIGN KEY (`GrapeID`) REFERENCES Grape(`GrapeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Berries`;
            CREATE TABLE `Berries` (

                `BerryID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `ReportID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Status`                ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                `PO`                    VARCHAR(15),
                `Location`              VARCHAR(75),
                `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Commodity`             VARCHAR(25),
                `Count`                 VARCHAR(20),
                `Size`                  VARCHAR(20),
                `Label`                 VARCHAR(100),
                `Variety`               VARCHAR(25),
                `Pack_Date`             DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
                `Grower_Lot`            VARCHAR(25),
                `Color1`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Color2`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing1`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing2`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing3`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing4`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Firmness1`             VARCHAR(5),
                `Firmness2`             VARCHAR(5),
                `Scar1`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Scar2`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Bruise_Count1`         VARCHAR(5),
                `Bruise_Count2`         VARCHAR(5),
                `Decay_Count1`          VARCHAR(5),
                `Decay_Count2`          VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix1`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix2`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Rating`                VARCHAR(35),
                `Comments`              VARCHAR(255),

                PRIMARY KEY(`BerryID`),
                FOREIGN KEY (`ReportID`) REFERENCES Reports(`ReportID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Berries_Photos`;
                CREATE TABLE `Berries_Photos` (

                    `PhotoID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `BerryID`               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                    `Photo`                 VARCHAR(70),
                    `Caption`               VARCHAR(255),
                    `Catalog`               VARCHAR(50),

                    PRIMARY KEY(`BerryID`),
                    FOREIGN KEY (`BerryID`) REFERENCES Berries(`BerryID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Citrus`;
            CREATE TABLE `Citrus` (

                `CitrusID`              INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `ReportID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Status`                ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                `PO`                    VARCHAR(15),
                `Location`              VARCHAR(75),
                `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Commodity`             VARCHAR(25),
                `Count`                 VARCHAR(20),
                `Size`                  VARCHAR(20),
                `Label`                 VARCHAR(100),
                `Variety`               VARCHAR(25),
                `Pack_Date`             DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
                `Grower_Lot`            VARCHAR(25),
                `Color1`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Color2`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Texture1`              VARCHAR(15),
                `Texture2`              VARCHAR(15),
                `Puff1`                 VARCHAR(15),
                `Puff2`                 VARCHAR(15),
                `Scar1`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Scar2`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Solidity1`             VARCHAR(15),
                `Solidity2`             VARCHAR(15),
                `Green1`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Green2`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Sugar_Brix1`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix2`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Rating`                VARCHAR(35),
                `Comments`              VARCHAR(255),

                PRIMARY KEY(`CitrusID`),
                FOREIGN KEY (`ReportID`) REFERENCES Reports(`ReportID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Citrus_Photos`;
                CREATE TABLE `Citrus_Photos` (

                    `PhotoID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `CitrusID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                    `Photo`                 VARCHAR(70),
                    `Caption`               VARCHAR(255),
                    `Catalog`               VARCHAR(50),

                    PRIMARY KEY(`CitrusID`),
                    FOREIGN KEY (`CitrusID`) REFERENCES Citrus(`CitrusID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tree_Fruit`;
            CREATE TABLE `Tree_Fruit` (

                `TreeID`                INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `ReportID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Status`                ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                `PO`                    VARCHAR(15),
                `Location`              VARCHAR(75),
                `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Commodity`             VARCHAR(25),
                `Count`                 VARCHAR(20),
                `Size`                  VARCHAR(20),
                `Label`                 VARCHAR(100),
                `Variety`               VARCHAR(25),
                `Pack_Date`             DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
                `Grower_Lot`            VARCHAR(25),
                `Color1`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Color2`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Ground_Color1`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Ground_Color2`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Solidity1`             VARCHAR(15),
                `Solidity2`             VARCHAR(15),
                `Scar1`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Scar2`                 VARCHAR(5),
                `Bruise_Count1`         VARCHAR(5),
                `Bruise_Count2`         VARCHAR(5),
                `Decay_Count1`          VARCHAR(5),
                `Decay_Count2`          VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix1`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix2`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Rating`                VARCHAR(35),
                `Comments`              VARCHAR(255),

                PRIMARY KEY(`TreeID`),
                FOREIGN KEY (`ReportID`) REFERENCES Reports(`ReportID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tree_Fruit_Photos`;
                CREATE TABLE `Tree_Fruit_Photos` (

                    `PhotoID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `TreeID`                INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                    `Photo`                 VARCHAR(70),
                    `Caption`               VARCHAR(255),
                    `Catalog`               VARCHAR(50),

                    PRIMARY KEY(`TreeID`),
                    FOREIGN KEY (`TreeID`) REFERENCES Tree_Fruit(`TreeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Lot`;
            CREATE TABLE `Lot` (

                `LotID`                 INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `ReportID`              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Status`                ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                `PO`                    VARCHAR(15),
                `Location`              VARCHAR(75),
                `InspectorID`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `Commodity`             VARCHAR(25),
                `Pack_Type`             VARCHAR(35),
                `Count`                 VARCHAR(20),
                `Label`                 VARCHAR(100),
                `Variety`               VARCHAR(25),
                `Style`                 VARCHAR(35),
                `Pack_Date`             DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
                `Grower_Lot`            VARCHAR(25),
                `Berry_Sizing1`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing2`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing3`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Berry_Sizing4`         VARCHAR(15),
                `Bunch_Count1`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Bunch_Count2`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Color1`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Color2`                VARCHAR(15),
                `Stem_Cond1`            VARCHAR(15),
                `Stem_Cond2`            VARCHAR(15),
                `Stem_Cond3`            VARCHAR(15),
                `Shatter1`              VARCHAR(5),
                `Shatter2`              VARCHAR(5),
                `Splits1`               VARCHAR(5),
                `Splits2`               VARCHAR(5),
                `Decay_Count1`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Decay_Count2`          VARCHAR(15),
                `Wet_Sticky1`           VARCHAR(15),
                `Wet_Sticky2`           VARCHAR(15),
                `Overall_Quality`       VARCHAR(25),
                `Sugar_Brix1`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Sugar_Brix2`           VARCHAR(5),
                `Overall_Condition`     VARCHAR(25),
                `Rating`                VARCHAR(35),
                `Comments`              VARCHAR(255),

                PRIMARY KEY(`LotID`),
                FOREIGN KEY (`ReportID`) REFERENCES Reports(`ReportID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`InspectorID`) REFERENCES Inspectors(`InspectorID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Lot_Photos`;
                CREATE TABLE `Lot_Photos` (

                    `PhotoID`               INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `LotID`                 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                    `Photo`                 VARCHAR(70),
                    `Caption`               VARCHAR(255),
                    `Catalog`               VARCHAR(50),

                    PRIMARY KEY(`LotID`),
                    FOREIGN KEY (`LotID`) REFERENCES Lot(`LotID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Shipper`;
CREATE TABLE `Shipper` (

    `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Shipper_Name`          VARCHAR(70),
    `Shipper_Number`        VARCHAR(70),
    `Website`               VARCHAR(255),

    PRIMARY KEY(`ShipperID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Shipper_Contact`;
    CREATE TABLE `Shipper_Contact` (

        `SContactID`            INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `Division`              VARCHAR(100),
        `Contact`               VARCHAR(100),
        `Address`               VARCHAR(255),
        `Phone`                 VARCHAR(100),
        `Fax`                   VARCHAR(100),
        `Email`                 VARCHAR(100),
        `Mobile`                VARCHAR(100),

        PRIMARY KEY(`SContactID`),
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customer(`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Shipper_Label`;
        CREATE TABLE `Shipper_Label` (

            `ShipperLabelID`        INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `ShipperID`             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            `Shipper_Name`          VARCHAR(70),
            `Shipper_Label`         VARCHAR(255),

            PRIMARY KEY(`ShipperLabelID`),
            CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES Shipper(`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: This is an invalid data range "DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00'".

Comment: @rontornambe I believe it is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a foreign key error.

Run this command:

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

And then look for the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" in the output to see details on the error.

**UPDATE:**
Now that you showed the exact error, here's a solution.

Set this environment variable before running your script, and it will allow you to create the child table before the parent table:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Comment: `#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation`

Comment: Here's a pastie if you want to try it out though, sorry I don't have super on this box =( http://pastie.org/private/frv9fnex2hxwfcalu0zmqw

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer. I think `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` is what you need.

Comment: Good idea, I forgot you can set check to false. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The Melons table was referencing a table that had not been created yet (was created farther down the line) the the reference for the Foreign Key, among other smaller error